# Alchemy websockets realtime data broadcasting interrupted when a client network has no connection?

Tags: websocket, real-time, alchemy

We are using Alchemy Websockets for distributing our real-time stock market messages to our clients using HTML5 websockets. Our application broadcasts and also send individual messages to client groups. Now, the problem we face is that whenever a client abruptly disconnects from the network(any network failure etc..), the server (Alchemy) freezes the broadcasting messages for 15-20 seconds before it continues to message other subscribed clients except disconnected client.

Do you have any solutions to overcome this error? Kindly let me know.

Comment: Do you have a way of specifying a send timeout? Can you broadcast in parallel?

Comment: Broadcast in parallel not available with alchemy and Timeout for a specific client is not possible.